# React: create closure that's referntially equal across renders with useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usecallback

I need to create an event handler in React in a custom hook and I'd like the event handling function to be referentially equal across renders for ..reasons (yes I do see how I can do this w/o but I want to understand).  Can I use useCallback as below to ensure the eventListener is referentially equal on every render by simply not mentioning variables it closes over in the dependencies (as below) or will that cause issues *even if* it's never passed to a child component so I don't need it to change value to trigger rerenders?

If not how can I achieve this?  Does it matter if I can assume delay and fn don't change (except perhaps it's reference)?

```
export const useVisibleInterval = (fn, delay = 300000) => {
    const interval_id = useRef(null)
    const handleVisibilityChange = useCallback(() => {
        if (document.hidden || interval_id.current) return
        interval_id.current = setInterval(fn, delay)
        fn()
    }, [])
    const clearInt = () => {
        if (!interval_id.current) return
        clearInterval(interval_id.current)
        interval_id.current = null
    }
    const interval_run = () => {
        if (document.hidden) {
            document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange)
            clearInt()
        } else fn()
    }
    const teardown = () => {
        document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange)
        clearInt()
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        interval_id.current = setInterval(interval_run, delay)
        return teardown
    }, [])
}
```

At a really high level, I'd like to understand what the dependencies for useCallback do.  Are they just to force reference inequality so child components that depend on it rerender?  Or does React memoize the result of function execution so failing to include dependencies would give stale results?

Comment: To elaborate, the reason I want referential equality is so that removeEventListener can always teardown all listeners.  If I simply teardown and rebuild the listeners each time I get a new reference for fn then I have to maintain additional state about the length of time since setInterval  last fired, whether or not visibilitychange is currently listened to etc..

Comment: And yes, I realize that in this case, there is an easy fix w/o this.

Comment: Have the memoized function accept the `fn` as a parameter?

Comment: The point is to use it as an eventhandler.  I need the referential equality to hold between the functions I use to call addEventListener and removeEventListener and those have to bake in fn.

Comment: I'm thinking the right answer is to just replace useCallback with useRef with the function handleVisiblityChange as the initial value.  But I'm still obviously confused about what exactly useCallback is doing so I'm not sure if what I have here is even wrong or what I just said is right.

Comment: useCallback is basically a wrapper arround useMemo returning a function. If you pass dependencies it redeclares the function with currently available values. You could pass a callback to `setInterval` that fetches the `fn` from a ref or state instead of passing `fn` directly. Then just update the `fn` in state when it changes without affecting your memoized handler.

Comment: Ohh, duh that makes perfect sense.  I see what to do now.  That's answered it for me.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it (if you want to bother).

Comment: But I wonder if you're in a situation where you're adding multiple listeners? I don't see you removing listeners except in your cleanup (which will only run on unmount), but you set an interval to possibly add a listener every [delay]...

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that, thanks.  It's obviously not what I wanted to do.  No reason I should be starting and stopping the visiibilitychange handler anyway (it already checks if there is a setInterval fn waiting to run).  Indeed, there is a whole lot that's wrong with this code :-(

Answer (score 0):

Based on [pilchard's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) comment I've figured out the answer (and that I was being an idiot).

The issue is merely about what values are updated when the function gets called with new arguments.  References *don't* need to be listed in the dependencies of a useCallback so the way I can do this is simply to replace fn and delay with references that take on those values, e.g.,

```
ref_fn = useRef(fn)
useEffect(()=> {ref_fn.current = fn}, [fn]}
```

And likewise for delay (or stuff them into same ref).  But, it turns out that I didn't even need the useCallback and referential equality and the code above reflects my deep confusion at the time and should be ignored.